# Does the plane have a countable dense subset? Does the plane have a countable basis?

Tags: general-topology

The plane $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ is the product $\mathbb{R}$ X $\mathbb{R}$ with the product topology. Does the plane have a countable dense subset? Does the plane have a countable basis?

Below is the way I did it, however I am not sure if its correct or wrong. Kindly check and also let me know how I can explain more on this/do it better?

[image]

[image]

Appreciate your help and support.

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ would indeed be a countable dense subset.  Thus the plane is *separable*.

Secondly, take balls with rational coordinates as their center, and rational radii.  Thus the plane is *second countable*.

Comment: I understand wat ur saying, but i really dont knw how to show it. Can u pls tell me how to show that?

Comment: For the first part, it's well known that $\bar{\Bbb Q}=\Bbb R$.  For the second, given a point and an open set, $p\in U$, there's an open set $V$ with center having rational coordinates, and rational radius, with $p\in V\subset U$.  You can use the diameter of $U$, and the metric to produce $V$.  You will again need that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Okay great, thanks!! wat abt the other one? Countable basis answer...

Comment: I tried to indicate how it would work.  It would require a little work, but isn't actually that hard.  The basic idea being that given a point $p$ and an open set $U$, with $p\in U$, we can find an open ball $B$ with center having rational coordinates, and rational radius, with $p\in B\subset U$.